# Trigger pop-up after a minute of session (across page-loads)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, popup, session-cookies

I am trying to find out how to trigger a pop-up after a certain amount of time within a session, not resetting when user switches pages. I understand that the easiest way is to use a cookie to track the session, but I have yet to figure out how to trigger a function at a certain time-stamp of the session.

This is a script that I think would be useful: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Any suggestions on how to approach this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: A couple of simple ideas would be to a loop on every page load that tests the timestamp in the cookie and pushed the alert() when the exceeds your max  or on every page load check the cookie and set a timer to send the alert on expire.   There is probably some more elegant way I've never used but those are two tracks I'd explore if I was facing your task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Set the cookie with the initial date.

Second, in your app

```
var minute = 1000 * 60;

var loop = setInterval(function(){

   var currentDate = new Date();
   var initialDate = new Date(Cookies.get('date'));

   if(initialDate - currentDate >= minute){
     Popup();
     clearInterval(loop);
   }

}, 1000)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I ended up doing a variation of your code.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up using (variation of Husam's answer):

```
if (Cookies.get('sessionPopup')) {} else {
  var cookieTime = new Date().getTime();
  Cookies.set('sessionPopup', cookieTime, { expires: 1 });
} 
var loop = setInterval(function(){
var initialTime = Cookies.get('sessionPopup');
var triggerTime = new Date(); 
triggerTime = new Date(triggerTime .getTime() - 1000*60);
if(triggerTime.getTime() >= initialTime ){
  console.log('Popup is up!');
  clearInterval(loop);
}
}, 1000)
```